# Cython: Import definitions from .pyx file

Tags: python, c++, import, compiler-errors, cython

I have 1 Cython .pxd file and 1 Cython .pyx file, the pyx file contains a `cdef` class:

```
# myclass.pyx (compiled to myclass.so)
cdef class myclass:
   pass
```

Now is the .pxd file of another feature

```
# another.pxd (with another.pyx along)
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
import myclass # This line is funny, change 'myclass' to whatever and no syntax error

cdef vector[myclass] myvar # COMPILE TIME ERROR
cdef myclass myvar2        # SIMPLER, STILL COMPILE TIME ERROR
```

When compiling another.pyx, Cython shows error about `vector[myclass]`, it says 'myclass' is unknown. Why is it so?

Comment: What you're doing will never work - you can't make a vector of a cdef class. The cdef class is a Python object and so needs reference counting and vector simply can't do that.

Comment: @DavidW how sad, so only c/c++ types allowed in .pxd files?

Comment: No. You can use cdef classes in pxd files. You cannot store them in C++ vectors.

Comment: and the line `import myclass` in .pxd seems ignored

Comment: .pxd files can only contain compile-time stuff. Therefore it'd need to be `cimport myclass`. That also implies that there should be a `myclass.pxd` (since `cimport` looks for a pxd file, not a pyx file)

Comment: @DavidW myclass is in another file, and `import myclass` in pxd seems ignored. Even putting `cdef myclass somevar` in pxd is not ok, error: 'myclass' is not a type identifier [i pressed enter for this comment slower than the comment right above]

Comment: That's because `import myclass` happens at runtime. The .pxd file should contain the compile-time `cimport myclass` (or probably `cimport myclass from myclass`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be clearly described this way:

- myclass.pyx is compiled into .so file
- But there are **2 kinds of stuff** in a .so file

  - Python definitions: Can be imported only with '**import**'
  - Cython definitions: Can be imported only with '**cimport**'

The problem is `import myclass` in another.pxd won't import `myclass` because it is `cdef` (Cython definition).

In another.pxd file, to import 'myclass', it must be either:

- `from myclass cimport myclass`

  - myvar2 will be: `cdef myclass myvar2`
- `cimport myclass`

  - myvar2 will be: `cdef myclass.myclass myvar2`
- `cimport some.path.to.myclass as myclass`

  - myvar2 will be: `cdef myclass myvar2`

There may be a problem with exporting too, especially using Python build tool instead of `cython3` and `gcc` directly:

- **__pyx_capi__** is not available in the .so file
- `myclass` is not public and aren't seen after importing

Thus better put the `myclass` under public scope in myclass.pyx:

```
cdef public:
    class myclass:
        pass
```